# Remove chars from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String and I need to remove a certain char from it and I have been able to do this, but I still have a problem. I get rid of the char, but the length of the string stays the same.

```
public class HelloWorld{

   public static void main(String []args){
       String data = "Hello World";
       System.out.println(data);
       System.out.println("string length: " + data.length());
       char letter = 'l';
       data = data.replace(letter, '\0');
       System.out.println(data);
       System.out.println("string length: " + data.length());
    }
 }
```

This gives me the output:

```
Hello World

string length: 11

Heo Word

string length: 11
```

I need it to be:

```
Hello World

string length: 11

Heo Word

string length: 8
```

Why does it seem to be counting chars that are no longer in the string?

Comment: Strings are immutable in java ... Google for it

Comment: @Scorpion That's not the issue here, he's reassigning it properly.

Comment: You must be a C programmer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `replace` is not right:

> ```
> data = data.replace(letter, '\0');
> ```

Java doesn't treat null characters specially. Instead, use:

```
data = data.replace(String.valueOf(letter), "");
```

This is because there are two overloads, neither of which is `replace(char, CharSequence)`. We therefore use the `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` overload (as Strings are `CharSequence`s)

If you're OK with redefining `letter` to be a String, you can simply do:

```
data = data.replace(letter, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not *remove* chars, just *replace* them.

Try this:

```
String letter = "l";
data = data.replace(letter, "");
```